# Ubuntu One Is there a portable version?

Tags: ubuntu-one, usb-drive, user-profile

I would like to be able to use ubuntuone on a usb drive while on the go. There would need to be a way to have a 'portable profile' that only synced certain things.

Answer (score 1):

No. Ubuntu One only supports synchronizing of folders under your user's home directory (or profile folder as it is called on Windows).